# Trouble at reloading map annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm making an app that should load all the gas stations and their prices on the state.
The map should reload the prices if the user selects a diferent type of gas (Magna, Premium and Diesel). This is made through a UISegment control.

The trouble is that when I reload the map it doesn't print the correct price (the default one is magna, and when I select the other type of gas it doesn't load the new prices).

This is my code.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    public let sMAGNA = "magna"
    public let sPREMIUM = "premium"
    public let sDIESEL = "diesel"
    public let MIN_TIME: CLong = 400
    private let MIN_DISTANCE: Float = 1000
    private var ubicaciones_selected: [Ubicacion] = []
    private var ubicaciones_magna: [Ubicacion]  = []
    private var ubicaciones_premium: [Ubicacion] = []
    private var ubicaciones_diesel: [Ubicacion] = []
    private let REQUEST_LOCATION = 1
    private var latlon: String = ""
    private var mType: String = "magna"
    var ubicaciones:[Ubicacion] = []
    var Ubigaspin = MKPointAnnotation()

     @IBAction func MapType(_ sender: Any) {
        if mapa.mapType == MKMapType.standard{
            mapa.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
        } else {
            mapa.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.mapa.delegate = self
        //con esto obtendremos la ubicacion del usuario
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapa.showsUserLocation = true
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //se cargan los pines y las gasolinas
        loadGas(tipo: mType)
    }

    func loadGas(tipo:String){
        mType = tipo
        var ubicaciones:[Ubicacion] = []
        switch tipo {
        case sMAGNA:
            ubicaciones = ubicaciones_magna
        case sPREMIUM:
            ubicaciones = ubicaciones_premium
        case sDIESEL:
            ubicaciones = ubicaciones_diesel
        default:
            ubicaciones = ubicaciones_magna
        }

        if ubicaciones.count == 0 {
            let url = URL(string: "http://192.241.214.56/api/"+tipo+"/?format=json")
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                if(error != nil){
                    print("error")
                }else{
                    do{
                        let ubicaciones_json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [[String : AnyObject]]

                        for ubicacion in ubicaciones_json{
                            let nombre:String = ubicacion["nombre"] as! String
                            let direccion:String = ubicacion["direccion"] as! String
                            let precio_magna:Float = ubicacion["precio_magna"] as! Float
                            let precio_premium:Float = ubicacion["precio_premium"] as! Float
                            let precio_diesel:Float = ubicacion["precio_diesel"] as! Float
                            let ubicacion:String = ubicacion["ubicacion"] as! String

                            let p = Ubicacion()
                            p.ubicacion = ubicacion
                            p.setLatLng()
                            p.nombre = nombre
                            p.direccion = direccion

                            p.precio_magna = precio_magna
                            p.precio_premium = precio_premium
                            p.precio_diesel = precio_diesel

                            ubicaciones.append(p)
                        }


                        self.ubicaciones = ubicaciones

                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                            self.updatePins(ubicaciones: ubicaciones)
                        })

                    }catch let error as NSError{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }else{
            self.ubicaciones = ubicaciones
                 self.updatePins(ubicaciones: ubicaciones)
        }
    }
    func updatePins(ubicaciones:[Ubicacion]){
        mapa.removeAnnotations(mapa.annotations)

        for ubicacion in ubicaciones{

            let anno = CustonAnno(ubicacion:ubicacion, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon"))
            anno.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ubicacion.latitude!, longitude: ubicacion.longitude!)
            anno.title=ubicacion.nombre
            //anno.subtitle="$\(ubicacion.getPrecio(tipo: mType))"
            self.mapa.addAnnotation(anno)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func changeSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        print(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            loadGas(tipo: sMAGNA)
        case 1:
            loadGas(tipo: sPREMIUM)
        case 2:
            loadGas(tipo: sDIESEL)
        default:
            loadGas(tipo: sMAGNA)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your issue is on this line `anno.subtitle="$\(ubicacion.getPrecio(tipo: mType))"`?

Comment: no, that one is commented so it shouldnt be the problem

Comment: can you check if is entering  in `if ubicaciones.count == 0 {`after you change your segmented control?

Comment: yeah i thought that too, but yes it does, funny thing when i delete the line mapa.removeAnnotations(mapa.annotations)  in func updatepins, the problem is solved

Comment: but it just overwrites the pin anotations, and the diesel section has fewer gas stations so i need to delete the other ones and i dont know how

Comment: I think your problem is with your ubications vars, you have a local var and a instance var with the same name, you need work all the time with your instance var instead of create annother, let me know if you understand me

Comment: you are also losing your information over and over again making your network calls needed every time you change your gas type

Comment: the problem was where i create the pin, but thanks for your help, how can i give you ponts?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if works, must work better i think, was not tested so let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with your `ubicaciones` vars, you have a local var and a instance var with the same name, you need work all the time with your instance var instead of create another, you are also losing your information over and over again making your network calls needed every time you change your gas type

Try replacing your `loadGas` method

**by this one**

```
func loadGas(tipo:String){
        mType = tipo
        switch tipo {
        case sMAGNA:
            if(ubicaciones_magna.count > 0){
                self.ubicaciones = ubicaciones_magna
                self.updatePins(ubicaciones: self.ubicaciones)
                return
            }
        case sPREMIUM:
            if(ubicaciones_premium.count > 0){
                self.ubicaciones = ubicaciones_premium
                self.updatePins(ubicaciones: self.ubicaciones)
                return
            }
        case sDIESEL:
            if(ubicaciones_diesel.count > 0){
                self.ubicaciones = ubicaciones_diesel
                self.updatePins(ubicaciones: self.ubicaciones)
                return
            }
        default:
            if(ubicaciones_magna.count > 0){
                self.ubicaciones = ubicaciones_magna
                self.updatePins(ubicaciones: self.ubicaciones)
                return
            }
        }

        let url = URL(string: "http://192.241.214.56/api/"+tipo+"/?format=json")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                print("error")
            }else{
                do{
                    let ubicaciones_json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [[String : AnyObject]]

                    var newUbications:[Ubicacion] = []

                    for ubicacion in ubicaciones_json{
                        let nombre:String = ubicacion["nombre"] as! String
                        let direccion:String = ubicacion["direccion"] as! String
                        let precio_magna:Float = ubicacion["precio_magna"] as! Float
                        let precio_premium:Float = ubicacion["precio_premium"] as! Float
                        let precio_diesel:Float = ubicacion["precio_diesel"] as! Float
                        let ubicacion:String = ubicacion["ubicacion"] as! String

                        let p = Ubicacion()
                        p.ubicacion = ubicacion
                        p.setLatLng()
                        p.nombre = nombre
                        p.direccion = direccion

                        p.precio_magna = precio_magna
                        p.precio_premium = precio_premium
                        p.precio_diesel = precio_diesel

                        newUbications.append(p)
                    }

                    switch tipo {
                    case sMAGNA:
                            self.ubicaciones_magna = newUbications
                            self.ubicaciones = self.ubicaciones_magna
                    case sPREMIUM:
                            self.ubicaciones_premium = newUbications
                            self.ubicaciones = self.ubicaciones_premium
                    case sDIESEL:
                            self.ubicaciones_diesel = newUbications
                            self.ubicaciones = ubicaciones_diesel
                    default:
                        self.ubicaciones_magna = newUbications
                        self.ubicaciones = self.ubicaciones_magna
                    }


                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        self.updatePins(ubicaciones: self.ubicaciones)
                    })

                }catch let error as NSError{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as answers that clearly explain what was wrong and how the answer solves the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy I will try to explain all, sorry, my english limitations sometimes make me answer a question with code